# Could I export the things that I taught my chatbot at Pandorabots?

Tags: aiml, pandorabots

I already uploaded a bunch of AIML files to pandorabots. But I can't see where I could export the things I taught it.

I understand from [this doc](https://pandorabots.com/docs/building-bots/tutorial/#learning), I could update my chatbot's "brain" such as from chatlogs. But could I export the teachings out eventually or it only stays only in the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you teach your chatbot while creating categories should go into the AIML file you choose. You can then download your bot in a zip file. You cannot see anything you taught it using the "learn" tag but as these are flushed every hour or so, it's not a good way to teach your bot.

Comment: Thank you Steve. What would be the best way to teach my bot while saving down what I taught, other than directly creating/updating an AIML category file? I'm looking for a more on-the-fly method such as using the learn.aiml ("learn London is in England")

Comment: Any facts created using the learn tag are flushed after about an hour. I am unaware of any other supported method apart from manually creating categories unless you create a bespoke program that will create categories for you. There used to be a tag called <learnf> which wrote learned facts to a file but this is no longer supported.

Comment: Also, the learn tag should really be used by your bot's users rather than you. It's designed for learning things like, "My brother is called John. Who is John?" or "I am wearing a blue shirt". You should teach/develop your bot by writing categories in AIML.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot. I hope I can code something that lets me train my bot anywhere I go, say suddenly I thought of something, then I could immediately teach her via my phone.

Comment: I usually just note down any thoughts in a file on my phone and then add them to the bot when I get home.